# How to fix Action Button on the screen in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an actionbutton and I want to fix that on the screen.
this my code:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  {this.myflatlist()}
  <ActionButton />
</View>
```

but when I scroll the flatlist,the actionbutton will hide and it's not fixed on the screen.
How can I float that on the screen when I'm scrolling the flat list?

Thanks, advance.

Comment: Did you applied a style to your ActionButton ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the position property in style of your Action Button.

```
 <ActionButton style={position:'absolute', 
    width:50,
    Height:50,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center'}>
</ActionButton>
```

Comment: thanks. but when I gave that position to the actionbutton, it is hidden!

Comment: Try above properties and please attach a screenshot if it does not fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `ActionButton` in a View and add to your stylesheet:

```
flex : 1
```